# iOS - Open an app with a URL Scheme from Chrome

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-chrome, mobile-safari

I've read many many blogs and examples of how to open an app from an `URL scheme` (for example, this [blog](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes/)), and it seems to work great when I call my app from **mobile safari**. For instance, when I call `testapp://some.data.here` in mobile safari, it opens my `testapp` and I can parse out the some.data.here.

However, when I call `testapp://some.data.here` in iOS-**Chrome**, it just googles the term instead of calling the app.

Is there a way to have iOS **Chrome** recognize the URL as a registered app the way **mobile safari** does?

When I google this topic, I see a lot of comments on how to open a url in chrome from an app, but not the other way around.

Has anyone encountered this?

Thanks!

Comment: In Chrome, you can't type the scheme in the Address Bar, but you can do it using JS embedded in the web page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the way that the Chrome app **appears** to be developed, it doesn't seem this is possible at present without a jailbreak (and even then, not easily). You should go [bug the Google Chrome iOS team](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/mobile/ios_team.html) to fix this (e.g. try to open in all registered apps with URL schemes before googling). Sorry I couldn't be of more use, but there just doesn't seem to be an easy way around it.

Comment: Did anyone find a fix for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

There is a complex workaround, but you're probably not going to be too excited about building it as it involves hosting a web server to dynamically generate pages with the appropriate redirect. This is a over-simplified representation of what we built at [Branch](https://branch.io). This includes some code to get you started though the web server will require a bit of setup not described here.

1. instead of testapp://some.data.here, you'll link to http://yoursite.com/hosted-redirect/some.data.here.
2. your server should listen at the route /hosted-redirect, grab some.data.here and build the following page (body here):

[image: code]
<sub>(source: [derrrick.com](http://derrrick.com/stackoverflow/code.png))</sub>

So your server will have to generate and respond with this page, filling in some.data.here, anytime http://yoursite.com/hosted-redirect/some.data.here is requested.

A lightweight node app could do this with a single file.

I just tested a static file for one of my apps and this definitely works.

Comment: I like the creative work-around for this issue. Thanks :)

Comment: Note that this no longer works well on iOS 9 -- will show an error message. Universal links are the way to go :)

Answer (score 0):

We can simply open the **deep link** using JavaScript which works fine in both chrome and safari in iOS.
If you want to achieve the custom url scheme using JavaScript you can use the below code: 
 *document.location = "testapp://"*