# "This app is not allowed to query for scheme googlechrome"

Tags: ios, swift, uiapplication

I am getting this error

> -canOpenURL: failed for URL: ”googlechrome:“ - error: ”This app is not allowed to query for scheme googlechrome"

I tried adding to the .plist but it made no difference:

```
 <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>com-google-gidconsent-google</string>
        <string>com-google-gidconsent</string>
        <string>com.google.gppconsent.2.4.1</string>
        <string>com.google.gppconsent.2.4.0</string>
        <string>googlechrome</string>
        <string>googlechrome-x-callback</string>
        <string>hasgplus4</string>
        <string>com.google.gppconsent.2.3.0</string>
        <string>com.google.gppconsent</string>
        <string>com.appcoda.gsignin</string>
    </array>
```

Why is my app not allowed to call `canOpenURL:` for this scheme and how can I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS - Open an app with a URL Scheme from Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13898573/ios-open-an-app-with-a-url-scheme-from-chrome)

Comment: what version of iOS are you running on and building for? how many requests have you made? do others work? how many items do you have in your list in the info.plist?