# URI schema does not work on iOS google chrome app

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, google-chrome, url-scheme

I would like to create a web-page, a page that will redirect to App Store if App is not installed in iPhone, and will redirect to The App if App is installed in iPhone.

I wrote Javascript like below.

```
function launchApp(){
    let URI_SCHEME = 'myapp://';
    let APP_STORE_URL = 'https://itunes.apple.com/jp/app/myapp/id111111111';

    let userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();


    if(userAgent.search(/iphone|ipad|ipod/) > -1){
       location.href = URI_SCHEME;

       setTimeout(function (){
           let aTag = document.createElement('a');
           aTag.href = APP_STORE_URL;
           aTag.Click();
       }, 1200)
    }
}
```

I tried this code, and in iOS Safari, it works as I expected.
However, in iOS Chrome app, it does not work.

To be more specific, when I tap the link button to the page that I am creating, the new tab opens but closes immediately.

Does anyone know why it does not work in iOS Chrome app?
Moreover, does anyone know better solution?

Thank you for your cooperation.

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13898573/2086991